# How to get the area of each grid cell ( for irregular grid)?

Tags: r, maps, raster, spatial

I am working with a global grid  where each cell is equal area: that is why my lat/lon are not placed at equal distances:

```
 data<- structure(list(longitude = c(-179.75, -179.75, -179.75, -179.75, 
    -179.75, -179.75, -179.75, -179.75, -179.75, -179.75, -179.75, 
    -179.75, -179.75, -179.75, -179.75, -179.75, -179.75, -179.75, 
    -179.75, -179.75, -179.75, -179.75, -179.75, -179.75, -179.75, 
    -179.75, -179.75, -179.75, -179.75, -179.75, -179.75, -179.75, 
    -179.75, -179.75, -179.75, -179.75, -179.75, -179.75, -179.75, 
    -179.75, -179.75, -179.75, -179.75, -179.75, -179.75, -179.75, 
    -179.75, -179.75, -179.75, -179.75), latitude = c(-78.07014, 
    -75.83873, -75.83873, -75.83873, -75.83873, -75.83873, -75.83873, 
    -75.83873, -75.83873, -75.83873, -75.83873, -75.83873, -75.83873, 
    -75.83873, -73.91449, -73.91449, -73.91449, -73.91449, -73.91449, 
    -73.91449, -73.91449, -73.91449, -73.91449, -73.91449, -73.91449, 
    -72.19456, -72.19456, -72.19456, -72.19456, -72.19456, -72.19456, 
    -72.19456, -72.19456, -72.19456, -72.19456, -70.62343, -70.62343, 
    -70.62343, -70.62343, -70.62343, -70.62343, -70.62343, -70.62343, 
    -70.62343, -69.16692, -69.16692, -69.16692, -69.16692, -69.16692, 
    -69.16692), m1 = c(2.23745321326184, 2.24038445612542, 2.3247780533395, 
    1.66920796399225, 1.97447588253218, 1.80588800929381, 1.30442582075186, 
    1.5896484492615, 1.44699114881535, 0.928007327323556, 0.895906387553201, 
    0.333973772256837, 0.219532053834574, 0.183666645885356, 0.436727878024647, 
    0.401417546671545, 0.425731067333535, 0.335518595275659, 0.259337721461039, 
    0.1902264040069, 0.191442551684625, 0.133596076817284, 0.123893680481917, 
    0.133860384950249, 0.120127435493534, 0.126049456057823, 0.106771777795723, 
    0.147704945619801, 0.147752100865098, 0.117718960396799, 0.0991150581382824, 
    0.0978849741864964, 0.114689160004564, 0.0933802168779779, 0.10092018847029, 
    0.105032230450153, 0.0722648215256436, 0.107400133838986, 0.108854539405822, 
    0.11324350965921, 0.0977313130700045, 0.103936014165899, 0.0947261373131327, 
    0.118145300616623, 0.0876853839421345, 0.0801285545866838, 0.100545927078964, 
    0.116151395720277, 0.14843963006203, 0.12462962629185)), row.names = c(NA, 
    50L), class = "data.frame")
```

Example of such tile: https://mol.org/patterns/richnessrarity
I would like to calculate what is the area of each grid cell ( it should be the same number for each grid cell). I wonder what will be the best way to do it since rasterize() method only will work for a regular grid,
lat and longitude are the center of each grid cell in my case

Comment: Why wouldn't you use an appropriate equal area projection so that you don't have to deal with irregular grids in lat/lon? Moreover, why not work with polygons when you're interested in area estimation but with grid cell centroids instead? Your data frame consists of 50 objects with only 6 unique geometries provided - so you're dealing with lots of different `m1` values in the same location, which might be problematic from a topological point of view.

Comment: this is a common approach that is used to make comparisons on a global scale. Since areas of each grid are same-  the estimates ( let say of biomass) is comparable. for equal grid area- I won't be able to compare cells like that since their area is not same. I would like to get a polygons. I don't know how to make them using an irregular grid.